# Kunstmaan ArticleBundle and categories

Tags: php, symfony, tags, categories, kunstmaan

Do you have any experience with the CMS Kunstmaan? We want to deploy it for a project and use the ArticleBundle. I have the task to handle categories and tags (creation, editing, and soft deletion), and everything is working for me. However, I have one issue: when editing an article, it displays all tags and categories, and I need to modify it so that it only shows the tags and categories that are not "deleted."

Thank you.

I have tried searching in the documentation (which is not very extensive) and on the internet (the same), in the configuration settings, and I have even attempted to search directly in the vendor directory to see where it's pulling from, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: you could try to get in touch with the developers or open an issue about the missing documentation details